# Crashlytics Crash not displayed on Firebase Console

Tags: ios, react-native, crashlytics, react-native-firebase, google-fabric

I use [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/) to implement crashlytics on my app.

It worked normally when my app use 6.4.0 version. That version not fully migrated to Firebase Crashlytics.

Then, I upgraded to 8.4.2 version that has breaking changes, migrating Fabric to Firebase Crashlytics [changelog](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/blob/master/packages/crashlytics/CHANGELOG.md).

**My crashes displayed on Android Firebase Console, but not on iOS.**

I've read and follow tips on these issues:

- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3879
- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/4229

no one worked.

What I've Tried:

- removed all fabric related code/config from xschme, project.pbxproj, podfile, podfile.lock
- deleted derived data, `Pods/`, `Podfile.lock`
- Upload dysm

```
[Firebase/Crashlytics] Packaged report with id 'dc5d9933e4c541c8a2f6ff7c6693713a' for submission
6.30.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] Preparing the report for the new endpoint: 1
6.30.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Submitting report
0 Flip[617:178559] 6.30.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports:Event] Sending event.
6.30.0 - [Firebase/Crashlytics][I-CLS000000] [Crashlytics:Crash:Reports] Completed report submission with id: dc5d9933e4c541c8a2f6ff7c6693713a
6.30.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 1568.5920ms
6.30.0 - [Firebase/Performance][I-PRF100009] Logging network request trace - https://crashlyticsreports-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog, Response code: 200, 1568.9490ms
```

Even though log `Completed report submission` is exist, there is still no crash report appeared on my console.

For more context, I used Crashlytics since it still owned by Fabric. I've removed all code/config (fabric ID, Fabric run script, react-native-fabric/SMXCrashlytics).

Any idea what solution should I try?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to check the below link. They have provided both Crashlytics and Fabric framework for download purpose. You may include them in your project and point your .dSYM files to it.

https://medium.com/swlh/integrating-firebase-and-crashlytics-in-ios-complete-guide-updated-2019-4526e9ab9c6d

Also you can download it from here - https://storage.googleapis.com/firebase-preview-drop/ios/crashlytics/com.crashlytics.ios-manual.zip

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue compounded by a lag in crash report time. My reports didn't log until a couple hours later, even though I was assured that manually crashing the app (as recommend [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash?platform=android)), would pop up in seconds. That said, from what I can tell, it was the addition of "Crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler" to my firebase.json file that fixed my logging.

`{ "react-native": { "crashlytics_disable_auto_disabler": true, "crashlytics_debug_enabled": true } }`

It does seem like Firebase should change it's docs (at least during COVID) to update the reporting time for a crash from 5 minutes...

Comment: Wah, thanks. Unfortunately, I've done it before, Jimmy. But it didn't work.

Comment: Bummer... You're using the force crash button, correct?

Comment: Yes. `firebase_crashlytics().crash()`

Comment: Have you disabled debugging by adding ```-FIRDebugEnabled``` to your command line arguments in Xcode per the Firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?authuser=0&platform=ios)?